# Groovy - Saving two json values (int, String) from REST response body to GlobalVariable

Tags: java, rest, groovy, automation, katalon-studio

We introduced a feature which requires certain user-specific API requests to include a new custom HTTP header, we'll call it `X-UserToken`. When the `POST /create/user` request is fired, a new user is created and the request body returns a `userId` and a `userToken` -- the `userToken` is then required to be set as the value for the `X-UserToken` HTTP header for all request specific to this user. (see below)

```
{
  "data": {
    "userId": 10023348,
    "userToken": "SampleTokenString.abcd.123.efg.sampleTokenString",
    "messages": [],
    "questions": [],
    "verificationStatus": "success"
  },
  "errors": [],
  "requestId": "abc-123-xyz",
  "status": 200
}
```

Before this change, I was successfully saving the `userId` int as a global variable and passing it into all subsequent custom web-service keywords in the same custom keyword script. This worked great. But now, I need to save both the `int userId` and `String userToken` from the `create/user` request and pass the `int userId` into subsequent requests as a request body parameter AND pass the `String userToken` as an HTTP header variable. The problem I'm having is that I seem to only be able to save one or the other, not both.

This is the *working* code for saving the `userId` jsonResponse value but I can't figure out how to save both the `userId` and `userToken`.

@Keyword File:

```
def createUser(String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate) {
    def response = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(findTestObject("Postman/User/create",
            ["firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "birthDate": birthDate]))

    def jsonResponse = jsonSlurper.parseText(response.getResponseText())
    return jsonResponse.data.userId
    return jsonResponse.data.customerToken
}
```

Katalon Test Case script step:

```
int userId = CustomKeywords.'user_Lifecycle_API.API_userFlow.createUser'(
    firstName, lastName, birthDate)
```

When I try and update both the test case script to include `String userToken`, I get errors. I've tried everything I could think of but nothing seems to work.